# How to change the gutter background colour in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

All the VS Code default themes (and any others that I've seen) have a uniform background color between the main view and the gutter. This makes it really hard to tell if you're at the start of a line (or to click there). Is the cursor at the start of the line here?

[image]

This is especially annoying with Python where indentation matters and you can't simply auto-indent a block once your indentation is messed up.

I often find myself pasting a block only to find that I was one space away from the start of the line and the pasted block therefore being offset.

Simply setting the gutter to a light grey background would fix this problem but looking at the default theme files I can't see any settings for the gutter. I've also looked at a theme from the store (Material) which has a few keys relating to gutter colours but changing them did not do anything.

Is there any way to modify the gutter background colour in VS Code?

Update: Version 1.8 of VS Code comes with a new setting to render the line highlight which can help with this when set to 'gutter':

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can change the gutter's background color (or colour) in `settings.json`. This was [added in May](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22410).

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGutter.background": "#000000" // your color here
}
```

or you can add

```
"editor.rulers": [ 0 ]
```

This won't change the background but it will add a line between the gutter and the editor.

Comment: +1 for editor ruler at column 0, which works regardless of the theme (no need to select a background color that works well for each particular theme I may use).

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that the gutter pointers are just not enabled by default.

Open preferences, workspace settings and set

```
{
 "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
 "editor.renderWhitespace": "all"
}
```

You should see the guidelines and whitespace, hope it helps.

For more settings like this check -> https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful but not quite what I'm looking for. This will draw vertical lines for every scope - or indentation level in python - and is visually very "heavy". I end up with my code dressed up in a pinstripe suite!

Answer (score 0):

Please install 'Python For VSCode' extension to solve the indentation issue.